# Figures are not displayed in html R Markdown

Tags: html, r, markdown, knitr

I'm fairly new to R Markdown and knitr.

I'm trying to add some figures to my report:

```
![my figure](/figure/another_folder/my_picture.png)
```

Assuming that /figure/another_folder/ is in current working directory. However I don't get any figures in my report, only question marks.

System info:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.0.1 (2013-05-16)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] knitr_1.2

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] colorspace_1.2-2   dichromat_2.0-0    digest_0.6.3       evaluate_0.4.3     formatR_0.7       
 [6] ggplot2_0.9.3.1    grid_3.0.1         gtable_0.1.2       labeling_0.1       MASS_7.3-26       
[11] munsell_0.4        plyr_1.8           proto_0.3-10       RColorBrewer_1.0-5 reshape2_1.2.2    
[16] scales_0.2.3       stringr_0.6.2      tools_3.0.1
```

I also found advice to run diagnostics report (on r-studio support pages):

```
> rstudio::diagnosticsReport()
Error: package ‘rstudio’ was built before R 3.0.0: please re-install it
```

Could this be connected? If so, how should I reinstall R-studio? My uninstallin .app? Because running `install.packages('rstudio')` produces nothing but warning: `Warning message:
package ‘rstudio’ is not available (for R version 3.0.1)`

Comment: Throw a `\`r getwd()\`` in the .Rmd to make sure you're in the directory you think you are.

Comment: Rstudio is not a package but a development environment (ie an "addon" to R that gives you handy features in the UI). Just download the newest executable from their website and install if you don't have the latest version. This may be your issue because markdown is part of Rstudio and its features..

Comment: Do you really have the slash `/` in `/figure/....`? The `rstudio` package should be irrelevant here, but you may want to upgrade RStudio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the problem was first slash. If I write like this:

```
![my figure](figure/another_folder/my_picture.png)
```

Everything works great. Sorry for misreading the manual!